# Resize uploaded images

Tags: images, post-thumbnails

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Resizing all images](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4984/resizing-all-images)

I have this news portal i built, and the client want a different size of the featured image.

I all ready made my first desired size and they have posted around 200+ posts all ready with that image size. Now, if i change the size it only changes on the new posts / or re upload of the current featured images(which is too much to do by hand).

My Question is, is there a way to resize the uploaded images?

Comment: Did you try [**searching for related questions**](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=resize+images) before asking?

Comment: Yes, yes i did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a plugin called [AJAX Thumbnail Rebuild](http://breiti.cc/wordpress/ajax-thumbnail-rebuild). It goes through all of the images in your media library and re-sizes them based on any image sizes registered (including the defaults and anything added with `add_image_size()`). It only runs when you manually request it and you can tell it to only rebuild certain sizes if you wish.

Comment: Testing it at the moment, will provide feedback.

Comment: Works like a charm, does what i need. Cheers.

Comment: Found another one that has more options for resizing http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/