# Bulk Image upload and one image for each post?

Tags: php, jquery, plugins

I have around 3000 photos, want to upload on WordPress. Is there any way to bulk upload all the photos as one image for each post ?

Comment: this is not really a programming related question

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is helpful: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/add-from-server/

See also: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=wordpress+bulk+upload+images google for `wordpress bulk image upload`

And there is also: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ stackoverflow for wordpress related questions.